# How to use Firestore set() method to update user fields without affecting required fields?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, inside the 'screens' collection, every document must have two required fields - 'creation date' and 'name' - and optional fields according to each user.

I want to delete all fields inside the document and rewrite new fields when they click on the save button. However, I don't want to delete the 'creation date' and 'name' fields since they are created when the screen is first created.

Since every user has different fields, I don't know what the fields will be, but every document should contain the 'creation date' and 'name' fields.

Please don't suggest using the 'update' method since I need to remove all fields manually before rewriting new fields.

I think the `set()` method is a good choice, but I want to ensure that this method doesn't touch the 'creation date' and 'name' fields.

There is no code currently, but I'm asking if is there any easy way to do that or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the `set()` method is a good choice, but I want to ensure that this method doesn't touch the 'creation date' and 'name' fields.

Yes, it's a good choice but as long as you call [DocumentReference#set(@NonNull Object data, @NonNull SetOptions options)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#set(java.lang.Object,com.google.firebase.firestore.SetOptions)) which:

> Writes to the document referred to by this DocumentReference. If the document does not yet exist, it will be created. If you pass SetOptions, the provided data can be **merged** into an existing document.

So in code, it should look like this:

```
Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("field", "data");
db.collection("screens").document("docId").set(data, SetOptions.merge());
//
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want the `creation date` and `name` fields to be overwritten, then **never** add into the `update` object the `creation date' and 'name' as keys. So use any other keys you want, but not those ones. In that way, you always have those two fields exactly as they were when they were created.

> but I want to ensure that this method doesn't touch the 'creation date' and 'name' fields.

As long as you never add those keys, you don't have to worry about it.